# Why are "colleagues" becoming "work colleagues"?

Tags: noun-phrases, language-change

I've noticed over the last few years that people who were formerly my colleagues have become my work colleagues. Does anyone know why this should be so?

(Perhaps I should also mention that the buildings we used to call "stations" have become "train stations". Perhaps these are specific examples of a more general phenomenon?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is called a *back formation*. That is, a class of noun which once meant something specific all by itself, now has rivals.

The classic example is *guitar*. At one time, all guitars were "acoustic" guitars, and so the "acoustic" modifier was not needed. Now that there are electric guitars, the term *guitar* may mean an electric guitar, so people who want to be specific about the non-electric version will specify an "acoustic" guitar.

Presumably you can have other types of colleagues than "work" colleagues, but the back formation here seems a bit redundant. There are other kinds of stations besides train stations, so the formation is more obviously beneficial there.

Comment: +1 Could you please give an example for colleagues other than work/project related? I always call them mates.

Comment: A colleague is an associate in an occupation or a profession. So you could be a doctor and a member of the AMA, say, and other doctors could be considered your colleagues even though you have never worked with them in the same practice or hospital.

Comment: I think you have the measure of it in your answer. I don't recall hearing "train station" before the age of "work stations" and "play stations" (bus stations have been around a lot longer). I've never heard of "colleague" being used for someone working somewhere else, but if it is, I can see how this back-formation might appear. Thank you.

Comment: @BrianHooper -  *Train station* has been around for 60 years that I know of, probably much longer.  *Work station*, in the sense of an office desk or computer terminal, goes back maybe 40 years, but the term in manufacturing goes back 100 years.  *Play station* has also been around for 100 years or so, in the sense of an indoor playground (as at a hospital).  None of these are "new" in any reasonable sense.

Comment: My wife has a fit about "Unsweet Tea"

Answer (score 2):

I use the term *work colleague* for those I see at my day job, and *colleague* for those I volunteer with. I think a few other people do this, too.

Answer (score 1):

I am an athlete & would consider My Teammates
“colleagues”  the same as I would consider the 
Folks I work w/ as colleagues.  Both groups I 
“work” w/ in a sense, It matters I suppose how
one defines work, or what one’s perception of
what work is, how play or hobbies differentiate.
Mental /physical energy can easily be expended
in both instances.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'work colleague' is a complete redundancy in my opinion as the definition for 'colleague' in a variety of dictionaries boils down to 'someone you work with'. I have never seen a different definition.

I would find it far more appropriate to clarify associates (using the AMA example above) etc. rather than to add a word that really does not add any value to the sentence.

The phrase is a pet hate of mine though so I may be a little biased against it.

Comment: There are plenty of redundant expressions in English - see rants passim.

Comment: Don't get me started on Chai Tea Latte at Panera.