# "Oriented" vs. "orientated"

Tags: etymology, differences, american-english, british-english, suffixes

What are the origins of the word *orientated*?

As far as I know, the correct spelling is *oriented* and *orientated* is not an alternative spelling but an error that is in common use.

Is it for example more commonly used in a certain country or by a certain people? Is there a reason for people choosing to say or write *orientated* instead of *oriented*?

Comment: +1 - I always get irritated when I hear "orientated" because I don't think it's a real word.

Comment: I added the British English answer below.  It looks like the question is already tagged as a British/American English difference.

Comment: _Orientated_ is very common in U.S. military usage.  If you're hearing it there, give up any hope of correcting it.

Comment: When we have a word-difference between US and UK, how can we get our commenters not to call those on the other side stupid or ignorant?

Comment: @BoofusMcGoofus - There are quite a few words commonly heard in the U.S. military that a person should be embarassed to utter in polite company. While not high on the list, this one would certainly be on it.

Comment: Canadian here, and orientated sounds ridiculous to me, though it now seems I will have to learn to accept it. "Okay, where are we? Let's get out the map and orient ourselves." "She began a new job on Monday, and spent the rest of the week orienting herself to the new office and its procedures." Do these sound strange to UK people?  To me orientate sounds as strange as the little Victorian skirts covering chair legs look.

Comment: How can we get people to stop calling English British English or UK English.  It's incorrect as the rest of the UK each has its own language.

Comment: you ask about common use by certain people or certain countries. I have a population of ESL speakers for you: Germans/Germany. In German, the word is "orientieren/orientiert", and people do the easy thing and port their vocabulary, hence "orientate/orientated". I also think some people go for it because it sounds more convoluted (first order approximation of sophistication).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

People say *orientated* because they hear the word *orientation* and think that's the verb made from it. It's called a "back-formation". (See [Why are "colleagues" becoming "work colleagues"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7945/why-are-colleagues-becoming-work-colleagues)). *Orientated* is accepted as an alternate by most dictionaries I've seen.

To *orient* something comes from the medieval practice of building cathedrals so that the *apse*, the part of the building that contained the altar, would be on the eastern side (hence *orient*).

(I suppose if they screwed up and got it the other way around the architects just shrugged and said, "Well, occidents will happen.")

Comment: Does that imply that it is a valid alternative to "oriented"?

Comment: It is accepted, yes. I've edited my answer to include that information. But it sounds a bit awkward and you shouldn't be surprised if educated people smirk or try to correct you for using it.

Comment: I wouldn't be. I'm usually the one smirking and correcting the people who use it.

Comment: You get +1 for the pun alone.

Comment: THWACK! (I'd downvote you for the pun, except I'm still chuckling.)

Comment: @Robusto. Also, "[In the Middle Ages many maps, including the T and O maps, were drawn with East at the top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map#Orientation_of_maps)"

Comment: After reading this post, I feel compelled to link to [difference between “alternate” and “alternative”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43659/difference-between-alternate-and-alternative) :-)

Answer (score 29):

*Orientate* is standard in British English, you *orientate* something when you point it in a particular direction, hence *orientated*.  In American English, you *orient* something, hence *oriented*.

[**englishplus.com/grammar**](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000245.htm) suggests it is more widely accepted in the UK than in the US but should be avoided in formal writing. I found similar comments at [**wordwizard.com**](http://wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=6986). I don't have the tools to do the formal statistical analysis, but growing up in the UK I don't think I ever heard anyone say the shorter form, hence my assertion that it is standard. I should probably have said more common in British English, and would love to see the stats if anyone can provide them.

Comment: Care to back this up with evidence? Personally I find "orientated" quite irritating. oxforddictionaries.com defines "orientate" simply as "another term for orient" and gives its origin as a back-formation from "orientation", as Robusto said.

Comment: @John http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000245.htm suggests it is more widely accepted in the UK than in the US but should be avoided in formal writing.  I found similar comments here http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=6986.  I don't have the tools to do the formal statistical analysis, but growing up in the UK I don't think I ever heard anyone say the shorter form, hence my assertion that it is _standard_.  I should probably have said _more common_ in British English, and would love to see the stats if anyone can provide them.

Comment: @John,ukayer: According to Google Books, on [the American corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oriented%2Corientated&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coriented%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Corientated%3B%2Cc0) ***oriented*** is about 60 times more common than ***orientated***. But if you follow that link and switch to the British corpus, you'll see that it's only about 5 times more common in the UK. So ***orientate*** still a long way from being "standard", but it's over 10 times more "acceptable" to Brits than Americans (and it's fine by me :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's still a minority representation in the UK, by far.

Comment: @Robusto: Not so much "by far" [back in the 60s/70s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oriented+towards%2Corientated+towards&year_start=1965&year_end=1975&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coriented%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Corientated%20towards%3B%2Cc0) when I would have been getting familiar with the usage (I charted *orient[at]ed **towards*** there, to screen out misclassified AmE texts). I upvoted your answer years ago because it's "correct", but I also upvoted this one because I personally prefer the longer version / invented verb myself (sod "correct"! :)

Comment: Don't think it's standard in British English... at least not in books. Check out google's ngrams data on on British English oriented vs orientated: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oriented%2Corientated&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coriented%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Corientated%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @AndyT ahh, thanks for figuring that out and splainin'! Also deleting.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, the existence of the two forms *oriented* and *orientated* is one of the many differences that American English has from British English.

I have noticed this in American television programmes where American people have used the alternatives *orient* and *oriented*. This has always stood out as different and odd to me. Not only to me. It has been noticed by relatives when I watch television with them. They have commented on how different and odd this sounds to them as British people. They, like me, had not heard it until quite recently, in American television programmes.

It's different and odd because this is not normal in the UK. In all my life, I have only heard fellow British people use the words *orientate* and *orientated*. This is what I learnt, as a child.

My personal experiences are confirmed by the following dictionary entry for *orientate*, which mentions “(US **orient**)”: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/orientate_1?q=orientate

Comment: To me, the verb, orient, sounds decidedly odd and I was totally unaware of its existence (as a verb) and its usage in the US until today. Glad you found a reliable reference to back up your "orientate" usage.

Comment: @Mari-LouA and Tristan, I agree completely, and I wish the various commentators who say how irritated they are by this word would accept that that is not evidence for it being 'wrong'. If I hadn't read this post first I would have assumed 'orientate' was the older term which had been shortened to 'orient' in AmE - rather like Robusto saying 'as an alternate' when the proper word is 'alternative.' I think :)

Answer (score 4):

*Orientated* is easier to pronounce in British English. Try to say it in an accent (real or otherwise).

- *Oriented*. The *t* sound drops off too fast because of the word ending.
- *Orientated*. Both *t* sounds are emphasized because they form the sound *tayt* and demand to be articulated.

Comment: Can people please explain their downvotes... if this is correct (which it very well may be), it is useful as it helps explain why the usage of `orientated` may be more prevalent in British English.

Comment: I don't know why, but it really is easier to say - a brit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm Canadian and have only started hearing "orientated" recently.  It sounds awful to my ears and back-formed as if someone is trying to sound smart.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently customer-oriented is more used than orientated.
Check out Wording:
http://en.bab.la/wording/

With the question "be customer ?" and oriented scores higher than orientated.