# Is there a concise word for "cough tea"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the word that describes a tea making coughing more productive. Is there any concise word for that?

Comment: What does "native name" exactly mean, in this question?

Comment: @kiam sorry, made it clearer now.

Comment: I'm confused. How did "tea that stops the cause of coughing" become "a tea making coughing more productive?" What is being produced, phlegm? More to the point, wouldn't making an activity stop also make that activity more productive, in most circumstances?

Comment: How can you have a concise word? Isn't a word by itself as concise as something can be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most teas that help fight cough symptoms are simply *herbal teas*. However, a term that encompasses all cough-treating substances is *expectorant*.

Comment: Expectorant refers to something that helps your cough be more productive. It doesn't stop your cough.

Comment: @Martha yes I meant such things. Stuff that makes cough more productive. Not just inhibiting it.

Comment: @Martha: I'm sorry but I'll have to strongly disagree with you on this one. Expectorants do treat cough by expelling phlegm from the nasal cavity, which is actually the root cause of coughing. You can ask the medical experts for enlightenment on this. All cough syrups are known as expectorants.

Comment: @Martha: Not incidentally, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expectorant) describes *expectorant* as *an antitussive agent*.

Answer (score 2):

Something that prevents coughing is called an "antitussive". (See [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti-tussive) Online.)

Comment: However, that's a pretty technical term, and not one I've seen applied to herbal teas.

Comment: @Martha: Don't [THWACK](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/oriented-vs-orientated/11875#11875) me again! I'll be good! ;=) Seriously, though, it *is* a technical term but it is the only one I could think of that compresses "anti-cough [noun]" into a single word. I'll grant you it's not a word I would use to advertise tea, but if you were to give me an example of a tea that actually does the job described I would certainly group that tea into the class of substances that are used as antitussives.