# "Orienting" or "orientating"?

Tags: verbs, differences, suffixes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oriented vs. Orientated](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/oriented-vs-orientated)

Both *orienting* and *orientating* seem to be in common use. Is there any difference in  meaning or usage? Is orientating just a common misspelling?

Comment: Yep , pretty much a dulicate, in my defense I did search before posting, but only for orienting and orientating, so it did not show up. Cheers

Comment: No worries!  This post will link others to the answer if they do the same thing as you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as *orientate* is another term for *orient*, *orientating* is another term for *orienting*, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

I think *orientate* is a back-formation from *orientation*, although *orient* is more grammatical.