# What's a word for "properly oriented"?

Tags: word-choice

While editing and improving [a question on the Cognitive Sciences site](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/220/are-there-axioms-in-the-mind/234#234), I came across the following sentence:

> Infants can detect an upside human face right after they are born

This sounded awkward to me and I struggled to improve it. I believe the author's intention was to say:

> Infants can detect a human face right after they are born, as long as the face is not rotated

or:

> Infants can detect a human face (in proper orientation) right after they are born.

But I really feel like there must be a word for "in proper orientation" in a context such as this. What would be appropriate?

Comment: This sure doesn’t sound very politically correct to me. :)

Comment: I mean *geometric orientation* obviously! :-)

Comment: You're probably looking for "right-side up" as in *Infants can detect a right-side-up human face from birth.* If you have to use *orient* you could say the face was *properly oriented*.

Comment: Apparently, the author meant ***upright*** not *upside*. I do not think there's more to it than that.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11874/2303

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***upright***
Apparently, the author meant ***upright*** not *upside*.

I do not think there's more to it than that. The preceding sentences in that post too have spelling and grammatical errors, as the author does not seem to be a native English speaker. No need to be overly concerned about these minor things.

Comment: I have a suggested edit pending which should fix the spelling and grammar errors. However I am confused by "No need to be overly concerned about these minor things," I am trying to remember the word I was thinking of. And you're right, I think "upright" is perfect.

Comment: @Josh: re 'No need ...," I meant it happens to us all sometimes -- we know the right word, we set out to type it down, but somehow end up with a near-homonym or a near-homophone of it instead.

Answer (score 4):

An answer is in the title of your question: "properly oriented".

> Infants can detect a *properly oriented* human face right after they are born.

Alternatively, the opposite of *upside down* is *right-side up*.

> Infants can detect a *right-side up* human face right after they are born.

Comment: I thought of "right-side up" but that also sounded awkward. I guess maybe "a properly oriented human face" is the best there is...

Answer (score 1):

While not the best for this specific case, in general the word "aligned" would work.

Something which is [aligned](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aligned) is in its correct relative position or orientation.  For instance, see [meaning 2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aligned).