# What is the correct term for "rubbing statues' parts for luck"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the correct term for the habit or action of rubbing statues' parts (noses, fingers, feet etc.) for luck or other superstitious reasons? I mean a learned word, like 'philately' for 'collecting stamps'. I'm fairly certain there is such a term, but for the life of me I can't recall what it is, and my Google-fu proved unequal to the task.

Comment: Don't go to Prague !

Comment: The term is *statuary frottage*. Not to be confused with *statutory frottage.*

Comment: @JohnLawler Damn that's clever. How long has that been in your pocket just waiting ...

Comment: @Frank: I'm willing to concede that he just thought of it.

Comment: @Robusto: I started off thinking they were the same, and it wasn't till I pronounced it that I realized I was confusing the two words. Pronunciation is everything. And Frank, I don't collect them; they suggest themselves to me. After 50 or so years of training, my xenophilic search-and-recognition daemons are running quite well, thanks.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I, on the other hand, waited decades to spring [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/oriented-vs-orientated/11875#11875) (since college, when I learned about the building and orientation of cathedrals).

Comment: @Robusto: yes, I've been fond of telling classes that I'm not there to orient them, but to occidize them.

Comment: I've looked for this special term but with no luck. Instead here are three links which lists the superstitious rites people perform on statues (it's not only rubbing, but kissing, spinning and stroking!)  1) http://www.lists-galore.com/2008/10/10-unusual-monuments-to-rub-kiss-or-pat.html 2) http://www.roadsideamerica.com/story/16084 3) [Italian superstitions](http://www.whattwocando.com/2013/10/italian-superstitions.html)

Comment: Wikipedia just calls it [statue rubbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue_rubbing). Check out the paragraph on health risks!

Answer (score 3):

I would call it *statue burnishing* or *statue rubbing*. Roadside America has an article titled: [Statue Burnishing Etiquette](http://www.roadsideamerica.com/story/16084).

I don't think you'll find single word for this practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think [*superstitious*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/superstitious?s=t) is the correct term for this practice.

In some parts of Asia I'd say it's more religious [*praxis*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/praxis?s=t); or just [*traditional*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/is-there-a-word-for-superstitions-which-are-meant-for-good), if you like.

Comment: No, this is a general term covering a wide range of beliefs and practices, for instance belief in lucky numbers or hanging up horseshoes.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy You may find the term too general, but it's unlikely that you'll find a more specific term in English.