# "Object oriented" vs. "object orientated"

Tags: programming

I've heard both used interchangeably with regards to object-[oriented/orientated] programming. What's SE's opinion on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Oriented" vs. "orientated"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/oriented-vs-orientated). I'd say ukayer's answer is the more balanced. The compounding makes little difference to the analysis. However, the omission / inclusion of a hyphen in 'object-orient[at]ed' (also already covered) bears thinking about.

Comment: In thirty years of being a programmer, this is the very first time I see or hear "object orientated". Never once heard or saw it before. Not even from people who didn't know the first thing about English, or the first thing about programming, or both. But that is not SE's opinion. That is my personal fact.

Comment: fdb, in the duplicate cited, answered 'According to the OED, the first occurrence of the verb "to orient" is from 1728, of "to orientate" from 1848.'  [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/orientate?q=orientate_1) gives '**orientate** verb [ T usually + adv/prep ] mainly UK ... (also {mainly US}  **orient**) ...  '. Thus both 'oriented' and 'orientated' have pedigree and currency. I'm more familiar with 'orientated' in the UK.

Comment: In the particular usage, the technical term is "object oriented", but voting for duplicate closure. The term "object oriented programming" was first used by Xerox PARC, an American company, in their Smalltalk programming language.

Comment: In my 40-odd years as a programmer I worked with a few people who used "object orientated", but they had other verbal quirks as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have three go-to resources for defining tech terms that I don't know: Wikipedia, Techopedia, and The Oxford English Dictionary (my public library has a subscription). All three agree that the proper phrase is "object oriented."

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming): Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm based on the concept of "objects", which can contain data, in the form of fields (often known as attributes or properties), and code, in the form of procedures (often known as methods).

[Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3235/object-oriented-programming-oop): Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a software programming model constructed around objects. This model compartmentalizes data into objects (data fields) and describes object contents and behavior through the declaration of classes (methods).

**OED:** *object-oriented* adj. Computing using a methodology in which a system is modelled as a set of objects (sense 7(a)) which can be controlled and manipulated in a modular manner.

Comment: In the software company I worked for, I always heard it Object Oriented....